# How do I set a longer timeout for post request before retrying the request Angular 4

Tags: angular, http-post, rxjs, settimeout, angular4-httpclient

I am sending a post request to my server which in-turn sends a request to another 3rd party API .. and this API takes a hell lot of time to send a response....
 the 3rd Party API sends an error if duplicate request is made.
Meanwhile.. after waiting for a while, angular retries the request and the duplicate error message pops up even when the first request I made is successful after some time.

I want to wait long enough before retrying the request and only retry when there is an error from the very first request.

I tried setting timeout to 1 hour and setting retry to 0, but none work.

Here is my code:

```
this.http.post(url,data)
    .timeout(3600000)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .retry(0)
    .catch(this.handleError);`enter code here`
```

Comment: if you don't want to retry then please rempove the retry option

Comment: initially i did not a retry option... even without retry option, the request was sent twice

Comment: may be its because of your  code. check it and confirm that there is no chance to call the request more that one time

Comment: nope.. I checked if I am subscribing to the api twice anywhere.. that is not the case..
I put a breakpoint on this.http.post line and control came there only once

Comment: I am also facing same issue, but not got anywhere satisfactory ans. What the hell http1.1 putted in its specification. Have anybody found any solution to handle it from client side. As I have no control on API. Team is saying why we are getting duplicate requests.